# How to limit a JS Object to be posted via ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, javascript-objects

I have an application that sends a message through `JSON` via `ajax`. This is the JS object:

```
var message = {
  "message_by": colmn[0].innerHTML,
  "message_date": new Date(),
  "message_recipients": [
    {
      "phone_number": colmn[1].innerHTML,
      "recipient_name": colmn[2].innerHTML
    }
   ],
  "message_text": colmn[3].innerHTML,
  "subscriber_name": "John Doe"
};
```

Which is then posted like so:

```
var url = "http://url/api/sendMessage";
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: JSON.stringify(message),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           processData: true,
           success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
               console.log(data);
               console.log(status);
               console.log(jqXHR);
               //alert("success..." + data);
               alert("Success. Message sent.");
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               //alert(xhr.responseText);
               alert("Error. Try again.");
           }
   });
```

The `stringified` message could look like this for example:

```
var message = {
            "message_by": "Brian",
            "message_date": new Date(),
            "message_recipients": [{
                        "phone_number": "0700111222",
                        "recipient_name": "Timothy"
                 }, {
                     "phone_number": "0800222111",
                        "recipient_name": "Winnie"
                }],
            "message_text": "Hello! You are invited for a cocktail at our auditorium. ",
            "subscriber_name": "John Doe"
        }
```

Now to the problem. The messages are posted to the api just fine but recently noticed some messages failing and discovered the failed messages had 100 message recipients or more. It works fine up to 99. I asked a colleague and he said there weren't any limit restrictions set on the api.

Is there a way I could limit the object size to 99 and push the remainder to a new object but still have it as part of the same ajax post? Is there any other creative way around this?

Comment: create a variable called iter, do a for(var prop in message) and set a max increment, once it has been exceeded send the message, create the new object , and reset the iter variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limit.

If you want to restrict your message  recipients to 99 you can do as follows

```html
validateMessege(message){
  var length = message.length;
  var messegeRep = message.message_recipients.slice()
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i+=99){
    message.message_recipients = messageRep.slice(i, i+99)
    // Your post request here
  }
}
```